# Where statement laravel I'm trying to pass id to get that id data

Tags: laravel

**Can someone help me how to use where on laravel I tried read some forum but still not working at all?**

```
  public function getStaff($id)
    {
        // $employee = Employee::get();
        $search= Employee::find($id);
        $employee = DB::table('employees')
            // ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'employees.user_id')
            ->join('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'employees.position_id')
            ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'employees.department_id')
            ->join('sections', 'sections.id', '=', 'employees.section_id')
            ->select(
                'employees.*',
                // 'users.email as User Email',
                'positions.name as Position Name',
                'departments.name as Department Name',
                'sections.name as Section Name',
            )
 ->where('position_id',  $search)->get();
        return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "Employee List",
            "data" => $employee,
        ]);
    
    }
```

Comment: In your `where` clause you're passing a complete `Employee` model, not an `id`

Comment: Route::get('/employee/get-staff/{id}', ['uses' => 'EmployeeController@getStaff', 'as' => 'getStaff']);


i want to get data by id

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an instance of `Employee` in the `where()` function which is not the right method to do it. you need to pass position_id in `where()` function.

Here is how can pass position id,

```
public function getStaff($id)
{
        // $employee = Employee::get();
        $search= Employee::find($id);
        $employee = DB::table('employees')
            // ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'employees.user_id')
            ->join('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'employees.position_id')
            ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'employees.department_id')
            ->join('sections', 'sections.id', '=', 'employees.section_id')
            ->select(
                'employees.*',
                // 'users.email as User Email',
                'positions.name as Position Name',
                'departments.name as Department Name',
                'sections.name as Section Name',
            )
        ->where('position_id',  $search->position_id)->get();
        return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "Employee List",
            "data" => $employee,
        ]);
    
}
```

Comment: this woks but only on /1 but when i do /2 gives me error

Comment: @JohnJayveeSiuagan And _what_ would that error be?